# Composition and multiple inheritance

Tags: inheritance, interface, go, composition

Since Go uses an composition system instead of (multiple) inheritance, I'm just wondering about these 3 code snippets. Go says they force the programmer to use composition.

A) should be (almost) correct Go-Code,
B) pseudo
C) pseudo

Imho the result will always be the same on all three codes, beside the fact, that B) and C) can be used for even more stuff and A) forces you to stick to composition?

Even if you assume B) to not have the sort-method inside of the class but - lets say global like A) doesn't make a real difference oO

A) Go code:

```
interface Sort
    Len()
    Less(i, j int) bool
    Swap(i, j int)

func (qs *Sort) sort()
    doTheSorting

type MyData struct {
    var value int
}

func (s *MyData) Len() { ... }
func (s *MyData) Less(i, j int) bool { ... }
func (s *MyData) Swap(i, j int) { ... }
```

B) Looks like Inheritance but can imho be seen as embedded, according to how the compiler works.

```
class Sort

    public sort() { ... }

    abstract Len()
    abstract Less(i, j int) bool
    abstract Swap(i, j int)
```

C)

```
interface SortInterface
    void Len()
    bool Less(i, j int)
    void Swap(i, j int)

class Sort implements SortInterface
    public sort() { ... }
```

Usage B and C:

```
class MyClass **embed** Sort

    int value

    void Len() { ... }
    bool Less(i, j int) { ... }
    void Swap(i, j int) { ... }
```

Comment: In your go code you implement a method on an interface. Go doesn't actually allow you to do that. You probably meant to make a function that takes a sort interface as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not how go works. Here is an example (pulled from the standard library) of a type that can be sorted.

```
type IntSlice []int

func (p IntSlice) Len() int           { return len(p) }
func (p IntSlice) Less(i, j int) bool { return p[i] < p[j] }
func (p IntSlice) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }
```

This implements the interface:

```
// Name of interface changed for clarity
type Sort interface {
    Len() int
    Less(i, j int) bool
    Swap(i, j int)
}
```

A type which implement the `Sort` interface does not get a new method. You can not assign a method to an interface such as in your example `func (qs *Sort) sort() {...}`.

However, it is allowed to be passed to functions and methods expecting a variable of type `Sort`. Because of this, I am able to call `sort.Sort(myIntSlice)` and it will then be sorted.

Here is an example function which takes any parameter that implements the `Sort` interface:

```
func IsSorted(data Sort) bool {
    n := data.Len()
    for i := n - 1; i > 0; i-- {
        if data.Less(i, i-1) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

In `IsSorted`, the function has no idea what the true type of data is. It could be `IntSlice` or anything else. What it does know is that whatever parameter you gave it implements the methods in the Sort interface.

I do not seem to be able to figure out the question you asked however. Also, psuedo code is very difficult to understand. Using another language such as java would have been better.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your reply, it helped me alot.

So what's missing in the code example here is actually the sort function which takes structs that implement the sort interface

func sort(s Sort) {
    //do the sorting
}

Comment: @SilverBln, I added an example function that takes a type with the Sort interface. I chose not to post the actual sort function because it is too long.